onEdit doesn't work on cells with formula
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) return;
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  
  var SheetName = "Civilian";
  
  if (sheet.getName() === SheetName) {
    var editedCell = range.getA1Notation();
    
    if (editedCell === "J5") {
      var oldValue = e.oldValue;

      if (oldValue === undefined) {
        oldValue = '';
      }

      sheet.getRange("K5").setValue(oldValue);
    }
  }
}

The script above is meant to check if J5 is edited. If edited, its previous value is to be updated to K5. However, since J5 has a formula, it's not working.
Is there a workaround to this?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. An onEdit(e) trigger will only run when a value is manually edited and cannot be used to detect when formula results change. You are apparently trying to track changes in formula results. See What is the XY problem?

I think that in your situation, as a workaround, your goal might be able to be achieved by checking the edited cell for calculating the formula of "J5". So, I guessed that this post might be useful. https://medium.com/google-cloud/workaround-detecting-change-of-importrange-using-onedit-trigger-with-google-apps-script-92748e25df60

If J5 has a dependent formula, set your onEdit function to check for changes on the precedent cells or ranges.
For example, if the formula in J5 is =A1, the precedent cell is A1. When writing the following sample edit function for simplicity, it's assumed that the example spreadsheet has only one sheet.
function onEdit(e){
  if((e.value || e.oldValue) && e.range.rowStart === 1 && e.range.columnStart === 1){
    // if A1 and only A1 is edited, do something
  } else {
    // do nothing
  }

}

Please remember that the values of e.value and e.oldValue will be the value and old value of the edited cell, so in this case whe should handle the values from A1 instead of J5.
In most cases, the best approach is to make the onEdit function do the calculations instead of relying on a formula. It should be saved somewhere if you need to keep the old value. One option is to use another cell, and another is to use the Properties Service.
